# Get % of rows based on total number of rows when using GROUP BY clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Using this SQL query:

```
Select CityName, count(UserID) as UserCount 
from tblUsers 
group by CityName
```

I get these results:

```
CityName    UserCount
---------------------
City 1      10
City 2      15
```

Expected output:

```
CityName    UserCount  Perc
---------------------------
City 1      10         40
City 2      15         60
```

As per above datasets, I want to get the % distribution of rows based on total sum of the value from 1 column. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a sub query to select the total count like this:

```
Select CityName,
       count(userID) as userCount,
       count(UserID)/(select count(*) from tblUsers)*100 as Perc
from tblUsers
group by CityName
```

You can also try JOIN like this:

```
SELECT t.CityName,
       t.userCount,
       t.userCount/s.totalCount*100 as Perc
FROM (Select CityName, count(UserID) as UserCount 
      from tblUsers 
      group by CityName) t
INNER JOIN (SELECT count(*) as totalCount from tblUsers) s
ON(1=1)
```

Comment: Won't it be too heavy on a SQL query that processes a table with around million records?

Comment: Not necessarily , depends on the indexes , amount of columns and many other things.. Just test it

Comment: Works, needed to convert the count to decimal to get accurate results. :)

Comment: No problem:) I'll appreciate accept to the answer if it works for u. @Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use window functions:

```
Select CityName, count(UserID) as UserCount ,
       count(UserId) * 100.0 / sum(count(UserId)) over () as Perc
from tblUsers 
group by CityName;
```

A subquery is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a Subquery/Join, simply use a *Group Sum*:

```
Select CityName,
       count(userID) as userCount,
       100 * count(UserID)/sum(count(UserID)) over () as Perc
from tblUsers
group by CityName
```

`sum(count(UserID)) over ()` returns the sum of all counts.

And instead of `count(UserID)` you can probably use `COUNT(*)`